# Spring Security OAuth2 клиент для android

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

Имеется небольшое веб приложение с *rest api* на *spring fm*. Для авторизации и доступа к ресурсам пользователя используется протокол *OAuth2* (spring security ouath). Все *flow's* работают как ожидается.

*Vk* и *Facebook* для своего *android sdk* используют отпечатки ключей *SHA1*.

Хотелось бы реализовать для своего *android-клиента* такое же.

Это является частью спецификации *OAuth2* или это кастомная надстройка самих разработчиков *Vk* и *Facebook'a*? Возможно ли это реализовать на *spring'е*?